# Access Query's data become editable when copy to another Database

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on a project with 2 different access files.
I have an read-only query from one file and tried to copy it to the other file.
The newly pasted query's data became editable. Anyone know why?

Note:

- The query includes 3 tables and a many-to-one-to-many relationship
- The two access databases have identical ODBC linked tables

Answer (score 0):

Check the query's recordset type. If it is set to "Snapshot", it's read-only. If it's set to "Dynaset", it can be edited.

[image]

The first query probably has a recordset type of"Snapshot", which makes it read only. The new query probably hsa a recordset type of "Dynaset" because is the Access default. Dynasets can be edited. To make the query read-only change the recordset type to "Snapshot"

Comment: The Recordset Type of two files are both set to Dynaset.
By the way one of the the linked tables are linked to SQL server views so basically they are not editable.
The problem with the other access file is that the table linked to SQL server view has become editable for some reasons (but if I try to add or edit record it pop up some error). As a result the query also became editable. (I can edit fields that come from tables that are not linked to SQL views).

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason. It was when I create the linked OBDC table, there was some option to select key for adding record. If nothing is selected then the table would be read-only, if not then it would become editable. I'm sorry for being silly there ...